# AWS Lambda: Call another REST API outside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda function written in C# with a HTTP API Gateway to expose the lambda function.

When I try to invoke another endpoint via httpPost in c#, the lambda logs doesn't display any logs and the request via POSTMAN to the API Gateway returns Service Unavailable.

Should I enable CORS or anything else? I tried to enable CORS but the result still the same.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

AWS Lambda functions running inside a VPC are never assigned a public IP address. So by default they can't connect to anything outside of the VPC. The only way to provide access to resources outside the VPC is to either place the Lambda functions in private VPC subnets with a route to a NAT gateway, or to create [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for those services the Lambda function needs to connect to.